# How is it possible to fetch after posting in react-native?

Tags: react-native

In react-native I defined a view which is exclusively for posting, then a view where all the posts are rendered through `.map`. The problem appears when it comes to user experience, it is annoying to "pull to refresh" after the user posted something, maybe even the first time the user will believe he didn't add any post. So, I want for the app to automatically fetch again the information after the user posts something.

So, let me show you my code:

```js
<Button icon="plus" mode="contained" text="#1ebc61" color="white" onPress={() => {
     this.addHomework()
     this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewSubject")
   }}>
      Add Homework
</Button>
```

Basically, that's what I'm doing when the users clicks the "Add Homework" button.

But I'm not sure how to fetch again the homeworks when the user is brought back to `ViewSubject`.

Some people told me this can be achieved using `Redux`, but I'm not sure how to use Redux in a class component. If there is any alternative other than using `Redux`, it will be great to know how.

Comment: I am sure, you are having a function for fetching data when the screen loads for the first time. Just call that function after posting completes. It will update the state as well.

Comment: I've thought about that, but how to call that function if it's in another screen?

Comment: Can you share some more code here, as I can just see a button which is calling a function. It will be clear if you show both screen's code and how you have included it.

Comment: If I’m being honest, looking at the code is not the answer as: 1) in the post screen I just call the function to post which is a POST request. 2) in the other screen I just cannot the fetch function that is another request but this time a GET request. The problem is not the code I have, the problem is how to execute the code when the user is returned to the screen. The architecture goes this way `ViewSubject->AddHomework->ViewSubject`

Comment: Is your addHomework() function async?

Comment: Yes, it’s is a sync

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212682/discussion-between-neetin-solanki-and-daniel-logvin).

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet, I’ve tried further investigation... but nothing really

Comment: have you tried code I provided below?

Comment: I use axios though

Comment: I have updated my answer with axios implement please check.

Answer (score 0):

Let me present a code snippet which might help you,

The problem is that your navigation occurs even before your post action is completed successfully, hence it can't fetch updated data in `ViewSubject` Screen

```
addHomework() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(YOUR_URL, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Button icon="plus" mode="contained" text="#1ebc61" color="white" onPress={() => {
                this.addHomework().then(() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewSubject")
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
            }}>
                Add Homework
            </Button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: But, here is my question. How is this going to make the last screen run the function that fetches the data?

Comment: It will just add the screen into stack again, so the process of that screen will be followed again.

Comment: Is your issue fixed?